# Python Django: How to stop Django from executing "POST" code when the webpage is loaded

Tags: python, django

I have a search field inside my forum's thread feed where users can filter posts. However, every time I load the webpage, the code inside request.POST is automatically executed without the user pressing the "submit" button.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="" class='form-horizontal' method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
<input placeholder="Search Phrase" id="search-input" size="70" name="search"></input>
<select id="search-category" name="category">
    <option>Title</option>
    <option>Category</option>
    <option>Author</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="search-button">Search</button></form>
```

And I have some code in my views.py:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    #This executes when the webpage loads (even though the user hasn't even pressed the submit button yet!)
```

Comment: If you are not redirecting after a successful POST, a reload could retrigger it.

Comment: Please show the rest of your view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's strange. In case this issue is cache related do you have the nocache decorator for the view. If not try using that.